# How do I install a specific version of crosswalk using ionic cli2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I currently have an ionic 1 project, but have just switched to using ionic cli2. I previously used to add crosswalk into my project, by running the following command, as mentioned [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/browsers.html).

```
ionic browser add crosswalk
```

However, ionic cli2 no longer supports the browser command, and I am unsure how to install it in the correct way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer is as follows:

I need to run

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```